# How to include .js file from location different than "_layouts" folder to sharepoint master page?

Tags: 2010, javascript, custom-masterpage

I would like to include js file from different location that it's now. Currently in master page code it looks as below:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink1" language="javascript" name="Company/Scripts/myJsfile.js" Localizable="false" runat="server"/>
```

and it works fine.

But what I'd like to do is to change current location of this javascript file. Target location of this .js file is a shared location (" \v-share\share\javascript ").

Is there any way to include this .js file from shared location in sharepoint master page ?
Or is there any possibility to include .js file from location different than /_layouts/.. path (e.g. "C:\Users\Desktop\myJsfile.js")?

I would be very thankful for your help, because this case is very importan for me.

Comment: Conrado: you can't register javascript file with links other that `http(s)://`. Actually, you could wrap the actual location of the javascript with a custom handler that will server the javascript over http, but it does not seems to be a best practice to me. If you don't want javascript to be stored in SharePoint, create a web application somewhere that will server the JS files. A bit like CDNs do.

Comment: And how I should define calling javascript file then? Like this: 1. <pre><SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink1" language="javascript" name=http(s)://Company/Scripts/myJsfile.js Localizable="false" runat="server"/><code> or 2. <script src=http(s)://Company/Scripts/myJsfile.js type="text/javascript"> </script>

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you Store your js files in Style Library of Site Collection's root web. In such way it can be easily accessed and versioned in case of updates. See below

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink1" Name="<% $SPUrl:~SiteCollection/Style Library/Core Styles/jquery.js%>" runat="server" />"
```

If you can deploy to _layouts (i.e. not restricted to sandbox) and you anticipate needing these libraries across many site collections, I would deploy them to a folder within _layouts. Generally, it's good practice when deploying into _layouts to deploy to a subdirectory within _layouts, something like `"_layouts/MYIVO"`

`<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink1" Name="~SiteCollection/_layouts/MYIVO/Scripts/something.js" runat="server" />`

Comment: Hey Falak, I'm using the link below to include my custom js file in a user control and it works fine, but NOT with an application page! Do we include js in an application page the same way or is it different?

<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="JsToAspx" runat="server" Name="(Path to the js file stored in _layouts)"></SharePoint:ScriptLink>

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Eliya, please see my updated response!

Answer (score 0):

You will want to keep it in SharePoint.  Putting it on your local c drive will not resolve for other users.  Typically people will load it into the specific SharePoint site if it is local, or into the Layouts directory if its globally accessed.

Comment: But the problem is that this .js file needs to be in shared location. SSIS package from other server updates data in the js file (the second server has also access to this shared location and it updates javascript every hour).

Comment: Why is an SSIS package updating your js file every hour?!?!?  You will have all kind of problems with caching and could have multiple versions of the js file executing all of the time.

Comment: I mean the package updates some variables only.
But my issue is how to include a javascript file from shared location ?

Comment: I don't recommend this but can you move your shared location inside the layouts folder?

Comment: It would be the easiest solution, but unfortunatelly it's not possible.